# Is using WireGuard keep-alive feature going to create issues when connected for long time?

Tags: ipv6, nat, ipv4, wireguard

My ISP uses symmetric CGNAT. So, for connecting to my WireGuard server over IPv4, I am using a persistent keep-alive settings of 25 seconds on my client to allow incoming connections.

Is this okay? Or can ISP detect/throttle it, if they find a port on their end blocked for long?

My network is also dual-stack. Is it better to switch over to an IPv6 endpoint on server?

Comment: What problems are you having? The question title says one thing and the body of question is just a series of questions.

Comment: Sorry, if it looked messy. I actually wanted to know, if wireguard keep-alive would work fine in ipv4 for a long time, because what I am thinking is, if isp finds a nat mapping blocked for a long time, won't that get deleted?
I edited the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They certainly can detect it (NAT state tables could easily have a timestamp and often do), but they probably won't bother unless you're using much more than just one port... or unless they're *incredibly* short on IPv4 addresses to the point that they have a burning need to monitor for such things. (That is, if I'm guessing blindly, the CGNAT would need to be worse than 1:256 or so.)

I'm not sure how CGNAT is more commonly done, but in what's often called "symmetric NAT", port numbers aren't exclusively reserved for one connection – the peer address is also considered, so that different connections to different destinations could in theory use the same "local" port number, making it less of a problem.

Using an IPv6 endpoint is still a better idea, though. (It could likely remove the need to use persistent-keepalive entirely.)